# cmake: how to avoid install dependencies of FetchContent and FetchContent_MakeAvailable when run make install

Tags: c++, cmake

in my project I have a lot of dependencies like grpc, protobuf, etc. Using FetchContent_declare and FetchContent_MakeAvailable the problem is that when I run make install command they are also installed, I want to prevent them from being installed and only install my project.

thanks.